# Some issues with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm passing through some issues while trying to make this code work.

The JavaScript part :

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value ;
var msg  = document.getElementById("msg").value ;
var date = new Date();

function post() {
    if (name === "")  {
        alert("You are missing something :)");
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
    }
    else if (msg === "") {
        alert("You are missing something :)");
        document.getElementById("msg").focus();
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += ("<p id='post'>Name :. " + name + "</p><br><p id='post'>Comment :. " + msg + "</p><br><p>" + date + "</p>");
        alert("Successfully posted :)");
    }
}
```

And the body part :

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>:. Welcome to the discussion .:</h1>
    <br><br>
    <p>The topic is : The structure of this website.</p>
    <br>
    Name/Nickname :.<br><input type="text" value="" id="name" maxlenght="32">
    <br>
    <p>
        Message :.<br><textarea id="msg" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="Post" onClick="javascript:post()">
</div>
```

I get some issues when I press the 'post' button, it shows up the alert even being with or without letters on the 'name' and 'msg' inputs. And I can't see if the 'else' part will work because I can't even pass through the first part :c . I tried everything, but no success, hope someone can give me a light.

Answer (score 2):

This section only gets run once:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value ;
var msg  = document.getElementById("msg").value ;
var date = new Date();
```

If you want to recheck the name value when post is called, you should have name be reassigned to `document.getElementById("name").value` within the post function.

Comment: In this case I could do the same thing to the 'msg' one, right ?

Comment: Yeah. The name and msg variables should be updated with the values of the given input elements when post is actually called.

Comment: Well .. Do you know how to make this part gets shorter ? .. I'm planning to make this little "forum" to work inside an i2p service, by this, it'll be useful to make as less as I can of scripts :s (Sorry for being boring, first time in a forum)

Comment: Sorry, I get lost right now. Where exactly should I put it ? @Ivan :s